# What is the angular momentum operator?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, angular-momentum, momentum, lie-algebra

On one hand, since the angular momentum is:

$$L^{ij} = r^i p^j - r^j p^i$$

so it makes sense for the angular momentum operator to be:

$$\hat{L}^{ij}= -i\hbar (r^i \partial^j - r^j \partial^i)$$

On the other hand, since the momentum operator is:

$$\hat{P_i} = -i\hbar \frac{d}{dx^i}$$

Wouldn't the angular momentum follow the same steps? As in:

$$\hat{L}=-i\hbar \frac{d}{d\theta}$$

I believe my confusion revolves around the generators of rotation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the chain rule for  partial derivatives to show that with
$$
x=r \cos\theta\\
y= r \sin\theta
$$
you have
$$
-i \hbar (x\partial_y - y\partial_x)= -i \hbar \partial_ \theta.
$$
Your two formulae are therefore the same.